# I have a problems. I need to split string variable in php

Tags: php, split

I have code which extracting keywords, this keywords with td/idf rating and other options are in $tags. Variable k-keyword consisting of this word. but if i want to print all of these keywords, this keywords look like: one long string, I need to have this keywords separated with " ", or ","...
 I have something like that in php

```
foreach($tags->keywords as $k) {
//$metTag = parseTags($k->keyword);

print_r ($k->keyword);

}
```

and output is

```
userarmethodrecommenddelivthidecisconsidactionruleadaptinformmodelcontentsituatbasiengagon-demandproactivmood
```

but I need output like that:

```
Array (

[user]
[ar]
[method]
[recommend]
...

)
```

Comment: What does `$tags` look like before your `foreach`?

Comment: Just for the attempts. try: `print_r($k->keyword); echo "<br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
print_r($tags->keywords);
```

Or this way :

```
$array = array();
foreach($tags->keywords as $k) {
    $array[] =  $k->keyword;
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: It looks like he wants the result to be a new array, not a multiline string.

Comment: Just as I posted in my comments.. This may be how the string looks, if so. This will not work

Comment: That's weird. I'm pretty sure there were no [ ] surronding his words. I just edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($tags->keywords as $k) {
    print_r ($k->keyword);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you've provided, it looks like $k is an object with the field `keyword`. Since `$tags->keywords` is an array you could try to just use `print_r($tags->keywords);` instead of the loop but this will display all of the fields in the array `$tags->keywords` as well as dump all of the fields in the $keywords objects within the array. You might also try `print_r($k)` but again, this will also print all of the fields in the $k object.

Another option would be to simply do this:

```
print "Array (\n";
foreach($tags->keywords as $k) {
    //$metTag = parseTags($k->keyword);

    print $k->keyword . "\n";

    }
print ")\n"
```